# Names for self-hosted GitHub Actions Runners

Tags: github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

The [documentation](https://github.com/actions/runner/blob/7b677e06187ab5b50254c3061fa1f25a93d659f9/src/Runner.Listener/Runner.cs#L559) for `--name` argument do not mention any specific requirements for a GitHub Actions runner's name and I could not find anything related in the [docs for self-hosted runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/hosting-your-own-runners/about-self-hosted-runners). Is there any documentation about the naming? Does it need to be unique (and for what reason)?

Comment: I guess this is a bit late to reply, but have you solved this problem? What name did you use that would not work? Your questions are a bit vague.

Comment: @AudioDroid There wasn't a problem, I justed wanted to know the requirements for the name as stated in the question.